# Is there a way to make postgresql listen on different ports?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am running PostgreSQL and I have to change between ports 5432 and 5433.

How can I be able to configure Postgres to listen to both ports at the same time?

Comment: You can't. Postgres can only listen on a **single** port.

Comment: You could possibly improvise a (man in the middle) relay, using ,for instance, netcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't be possible to run the Postgres server in multiple ports. But you can use `socat` or `ip tables` in Linux or use proxy like [pgbouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/)

But sample way you can use `socat` connection for listening in another port

```sh
# Postgres service listen in port 5432
socat -dddd TCP4-LISTEN:5433,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:my-postgres-address:5432
```

Comment: when I run that, I get the following error `2021/12/14 14:15:21 socat[31284] E getaddrinfo("my-postgres-address", "NULL", {1,2,1,6}, {}): Name or service not known
`

Comment: You should change `my-postgres-address` with domain or IP address. like: `socat -dddd TCP4-LISTEN:5433,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:192.168.1.1:5432`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can make this:

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5436 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=5432 connectaddress=127.0.0.1